# api.ai max of 4 required parameters

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a conversation but I have managed to hit a stumbling block. It looks like I can only have 4 required parameters ....
Here is a screenshot of my intent:

[image]

This will work with no issues, but if I add another required parameter, when my conversation gets to that last required parameter prompt, it never accepts the text I put in.
Does anyone know if this is by design? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems from your screenshot that you are missing the $ sign before the value for 'step2' and 'category'. You need to define for them an entity and set the value with a variable like you did in the first 4 rows. As for the require, it should work... But from the voice UI, I wouldn't force the user to say all these things in one intent. Try to break it down, so it will be easier to give limited set of details as an answer.

Comment: category and step2 are context answers. That's why they don't have $ signs

Comment: Got it... I have an example with 7 params and it is working. I wonder why you aren't see it.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, I have no idea why it wasn't. But I created a new intent and tried again and it worked fine. As far as I can tell, it was exactly the same as the one above